# Matlab linking two files

Tags: function, matlab

How can I use output data from one m-file as an input variable in another m-file? I have two m-file functions wheres the results from one is needed to be used as an input for another

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have `f.m` and `v.m` and you want the output of the first to be the output of the second, then do `f(v)` . Ofcourse `f.m` must have the function f defined as:

```
function o=f(aval)

  %dosomething here

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to modify the m-file into the form of a function, it is possible to run a script file from within a function, which can then return variables created by the script. For example

```
% my_script.m
t = 5*q;
l = 7;
```

and

```
function l = my_function(q)
my_script;
```

You will see that the Matlab code analyser complains the return variable `l` may not be assigned: it does not inspect the script being called. This is, however, OK. Any variables used by the script must be passed in as function arguments, even if (as with `q`) they are not needed to calculate the outputs. Variables created by the script which are unwanted, e.g. `t`, can be left off the return variable list, and will be cleared when the function exits.